# Prebid Server Not Returning Ads

Tags: server, prebid

I'm setting up a Prebid ***Server*** sandbox on my machine. I'm using the example code/objects from the PBS project.  When I make a call to the auction to get a sample ad, I'm expecting to get back the sample 'hello world' object found at http://prebid.org/prebid-server/endpoints/openrtb2/auction.html but instead I'm a very small data object (listed below) that is missing critical things like the bid and bid.adm.  Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks.

The Endpoint URL: 
http://localhost:8000/openrtb2/auction

```
The Post Data Object: 
{
    "id": "some-request-id",
    "site": {
      "page": "prebid.org"
    },
    "imp": [
      {
        "id": "some-impression-id",
        "banner": {
          "format": [
            {
              "w": 300,
              "h": 250
            },
            {
              "w": 300,
              "h": 600
            }
          ]
        },
        "ext": {
          "appnexus": {
            "placementId": 10433394
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "tmax": 5000
  }
```

```
The Return Object:

{
    "id": "some-request-id",
    "ext": {
        "responsetimemillis": {
            "appnexus": 120
        },
        "tmaxrequest": 5000
    }
}
```

[image: Postman Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you can send over a page to look at, however, for further debugging on the client and server side you can do add &debug=1 on the request to localhost:8000/openrtb2/auction.

I suspect there is a setup problem with your instance of Prebid Client side, which needs to receive this bid and pass it to the client side auction to finish the process.